# Wordpress enqueuing stylesheet as script

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a weird situation going on. I'm currently working on localhost. Wordpress seems to be enqueuing my stylesheet as a script. Below is a screenshot and and a snippet of the enqueue code. The stylesheet is also throwing errors in the console, as if being interpreted as a script.

[image: Screenshot]

```
if ( is_page_template( 'page-templates/fullpage-scroll-template.php' ) ) {
    wp_register_script( 'fullpage-css', trailingslashit( get_template_directory_uri() ) . 'css/fullpage.css' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'fullpage-css' );
  }
```

Comment: use `wp_enqueue_style` instead `wp_enqueue_script`

Comment: ahhhhhhhhh dang it so obvious!!! I feel like an ass

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org. for any problems always check Codex!

Comment: Yeah I know. More of a tired eye situation really. Thanks!

Comment: One thing I know that has been confusing for me in the past is that when you want to use either the `wp_enqueue_script` or the `wp_enqueue_style` function in the functions.php file, you normally attach it to the `wp_enqueue_scripts` action/hook. ( [codex.wordpress.org](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_enqueue_scripts) ). If there is any other take on this I'd be excited to know about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as prometheus pointed out there, it should be `wp_enqueue_style` NOT `wp_enqueue_script`

```
if ( is_page_template( 'page-templates/fullpage-scroll-template.php' ) ) {
wp_register_style( 'fullpage-css', trailingslashit( get_template_directory_uri() ) . 'css/fullpage.css' );
wp_enqueue_style( 'fullpage-css' );
 }
```